# Getting error when using civix generate:module or civix generate:entity curly braces no longer supported in phar

Tags: civix

Getting this error when using civix to generate a module or an entity:

```
Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in phar:///usr/local/bin/civix/vendor/civicrm/cv/src/BuildkitReader.php on line 38
```

Can anyone explain what could be causing this and what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**: The PR was merged so now the latest civix phar download supports php 7.4 (insert emoji yay! here)

---

**UPDATE**: PR submitted to update civix to update its version of cv: https://github.com/totten/civix/pull/200

---

Are you on php 7.4? You have an old version of cv within your civix phar. I'd download a new copy of civix.

i.e. https://github.com/civicrm/cv/commit/018c667429653ca06bc1dff6a93fdec87d9171bc

Comment: Hmm I think I have the latest, if I do civix --version I get: civix version v20.09.0-5-g68860ca

Comment: Oh I see - civix is only requiring v.2 of cv but the fix is in v.3. Civix itself needs its composer.json updated and a new download compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I downloaded the latest version but my local PHP was 8.0. Switched to 7.2 (which is the one my local apache is using) and it works again.